# Erro MethodNotAllowedHttpException no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando atualizar dados, porém recebo:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Minha rota:

```
Route::put('animalperdido/{id}', 'AnimalPerdidoController@update');
```

Minha função:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $animalPerdido = AnimalPerdido::findOrFail($id);
    $animalPerdido->update($request->all());

    return $animalPerdido;
}
```

No postman estou tentando passar no header o id e no body uma chave que deve ser alterada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando fazer uma requisição diferente da qual a sua rota espera.

Routes.php

```
Route::put('animalperdido/{id}', 'AnimalPerdidoController@update');
```

Utilize a diretiva do Blade `@method` no seu formulário HTML

```
<form action="{{url('/animalperdido/ID_ANIMAL_PERDIDO')}}" method="post">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf

    ...
</form>
```

Consulte a documentação para maiores informações:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers

Comment: eu uso o angular no frontend, só uso o laravel pra criar as API

Comment: mas deu pra entender o problema